# Could someone check my document code?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm a PhD student writing his thesis on overleaf and been getting more than 400 errors. Could someone help?

```
\documentclass[12pt, thesis]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{$-$}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont={color=blue,bf},up]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt} % less gaps in itemize sections
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries
        % \@chapapp\space % removed
        \thechapter
        \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 15\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{20pt}{3pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\parskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5\textfloatsep}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{10pt}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}
\author{Davide Vincenzo Verdolino}

\date{28 February 2021}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/header1.png}
        \begin{singlespace}
        \vspace*{2.5cm} \par
        \Huge \bf {Understanding the mechanisms of action of collagen-based wound dressings to promote healing.}
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \vskip 2.0cm \par
        \large \bf{A thesis submitted to the University of Manchester for the \\ degree of Doctor of Philosophy \\ in the Faculty of Science and Engineering} \par
         \vskip 3.0cm \par
        \large {Davide Vincenzo  Verdolino} \par
        \large {9767515}
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \vskip 0.8cm \par
        \large \normalfont {Supervised by Prof. Sarah Cartmell} \par
        \large \normalfont {In collaboration with 3M Company} \par
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \large \normalfont {The University of Manchester \\ Henry Royce Institute, Royce Hub Building \\ Department of Materials  \\ School of Natural Sciences \\ Faculty of Science and Engineering} \par
        \vskip 0.8cm
        \large \normalfont {September 2023}
        \end{singlespace}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
        
    \tableofcontents
    
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}  
    \listoftables
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \input{Intro}

    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \chapter{\textit{In Vitro} Characterisation}
    \endgroup
    \input{Chapter 2}
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

The first error I get is

```
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).
<inserted text> 
                $
l.15 ...$=$2 biological replicates.\relax }}{58}{}
                                                  % 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 19347 strings out of 477678
 352358 string characters out of 5829488
 1210596 words of memory out of 5000000
 37771 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 479410 words of font info for 98 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,6n,77p,1146b,1898s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Which refers to this line of code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/Neutrophils Chemotaxis.png}
    \caption{Neutrophils migration as a result of exposure to wound dressings extract (10 mg/mL), DMEM (negative control) and fMLP (1$\mu$M, positive control). * P<0.05, ** P<0.01, *** P<0.001, **** P<0.0001, \bullet P<0.0001 against fMLP, \bullet\bullet P<0.001 against fMLP. Error bars represented SEM of n$=$6 replicates across n$=$3 separate experiments from n$=$2 biological replicates.}
    \label{neut_chemo}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried using (=) and {=} but still getting the same error.

Comment: `\bullet` needs to be `$\bullet$`, otherwise use `\textbullet`. Regardless, your question is poorly formed without much of the context that could help the audience here. Can you trim the problem down into a minimal example that still replicates the issue?

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled unless one has access to the files `Intro.tex`, `Chapter 2.tex`, and `Thesis.bib`..

Comment: not the cause of your error, never use `n$=$2 ` use `$n=2$` or if you want it as text not math `n = 2`

Comment: you should clean up your preamble. You are loading packages twice and there is no order.

Comment: don't use `{}` with size commands such as `\large`: ` \large {Davide V`

Comment: 400 error messages does not mean that there are 400 mistakes. One mistake can result in several error messages. So always start with the first error and after correcting it, do a new LaTeX run and continue with the new first error …

Comment: Do please follow @UlrikeFischer's advice to clean up your preamble. For instance, there's no justification for -- and no excuse for -- loading the `graphicx`, `titlesec`, `wrapfig`, and `xcolor` packages twice. Then, consider which packages aren't needed and hence shouldn't be loaded to begin with.

Comment: Two letter font commands such as `\bf` (1) don't take arguments and (2) shouldn't be used in LaTeX at all. Use `{\bfseries ....}` or `\textbf{...}`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by specifying the `thesis` document class option? Neither the `report` document class nor any of the packages you load make use of the `thesis` option. Hence, the log file should contain the following warning message: "LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [thesis]". Don't ignore it.

Comment: @Mico it was a file created from a professor at my institution. I fixed it. Never realised there was a warning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code block

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/Neutrophils Chemotaxis.png}
    \caption{Neutrophils migration as a result of exposure to wound 
    dressings extract (10 mg/mL), DMEM (negative control) and fMLP 
    (1$\mu$M, positive control). * P<0.05, ** P<0.01, *** P<0.001, 
    **** P<0.0001, \bullet P<0.0001 against fMLP, \bullet\bullet 
    P<0.001 against fMLP. Error bars represented SEM of n$=$6 
    replicates across n$=$3 separate experiments from n$=$2 
    biological replicates.}
    \label{neut_chemo}
\end{figure}
```

will compile a whole lot better if you rewrite it as

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Neutrophils Chemotaxis.png}
    \caption{Neutrophils migration as a result of exposure to wound 
    dressings extract (10 mg/mL), DMEM (negative control) and fMLP 
    (1$\mu$M, positive control).}
    \label{neut_chemo}

    \medskip\footnotesize
    $^{*}$ $P<0.05$, $^{**}$ $P<0.01$, $^{***}$ $P<0.001$, $^{****}$ $P<0.0001$;  
    $^{\bullet}$ $P<0.0001$ against fMLP, $^{\bullet\bullet}$ $P<0.001$ 
    against fMLP. Error bars represented SEM of n$=$6 replicates 
    across n$=$3 separate experiments from n$=$2 biological replicates.}
\end{figure}
```

Note that I recommend removing legend material from the argument of `\caption` and placing it below the caption. No need to overburden the attention span of your readers with excessively long captions...

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{report} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,
            labelfont={color=blue,bf},up]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % <-- new, for \qty macro
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Neutrophils Chemotaxis.png}
    \caption{Neutrophils migration as a result of exposure to wound 
    dressings extract (\qty{10}{\milli\gram\per\milli\liter}), 
    DMEM (negative control) and fMLP (\qty{1}{\micro M}, positive control).}
    \label{neut_chemo}

    \medskip\footnotesize
    $^{*}$ $P<0.05$, $^{**}$ $P<0.01$, $^{***}$ $P<0.001$, $^{****}$ $P<0.0001$; 
    $^{\bullet}$ $P<0.0001$ against fMLP, $^{\bullet\bullet}$ $P<0.001$ 
    against fMLP. Error bars represented SEM of $n=6$ replicates 
    across $n=3$ separate experiments from $n=2$ biological replicates.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put the legend itself in a tabular, or even use a pgfplots legend.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Absolutely!

Comment: @Mico You shouldn't put the asterisks in math mode. The * is a binary
operation and the spacing for **, ***, and **** is different. I assume
they just represent reference labels.

Comment: @UdoWermuth - I'm afraid I have to disagree with your claim that "* is a binary operation". The groups of one, two, three, and four asterisks can only denote decreasing levels of probability or, viewed differently, increasing levels of statistical significance of rejecting some hypothesis involving experiments involving "biological replicates", whatever that may be. Same for the cases of one and two bullets. Aside: I'm surmising that fMLP is short for "N-formylMethionine-Leucyl-Phenylalanine".

Comment: @Mico Sorry, my second sentence should start with _For TeX the_ instead of
_The_; the _reference labels_ were a guess, of course. Obviously
the white space that TeX adds around the second * in the output is
intended in this application domain.

Comment: @UdoWermuth - Many thanks for your follow-up comments -- I will admit that I hadn't even noticed until now that there was a spacing issue associated with the asterisks. I'll go ahead and update the code and the associated screenshot.